# Loading a sparse matrix Armadillo C++

Tags: c++, matrix, sparse-matrix, armadillo

I'm having a bit of a strange problem.  I generally use the CLion IDE to compile and run code but I want to make use of a profiler to try to optimize my software and CLion does not include a profiler extension.  So I need to compile and run at command line.

OK, no problem but for some reason when I do so, I get errors when loading sparse matrices saved in the form arma_binary (which the Armadillo documentation states is the only possible file format for sparse matrices).

The following is an example script saved as `main.cpp`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <armadillo>


using namespace std;
using namespace arma;

void DenseMult (mat& I, mat& B);
void SparseMult (sp_mat& I, mat& B);

int main() {

    mat Int; Int.load("intMatDense.mat");
    cout << Int.n_cols << endl;

    sp_mat IntSp; IntSp.load("intMatSparse.mat", arma_binary);
    cout << IntSp.n_cols << endl;

    mat B; B.load("biomassMat.mat");

    DenseMult(Int, B);

    SparseMult(IntSp, B);

    return 0;
}

void DenseMult (mat& I, mat& B) {
    I * B;
}

void SparseMult (sp_mat& I, mat& B) {
    I * B;
}
```

Which gives the following output when built and run in CLion:

```
/home/jack/CLionProjects/Optimization/cmake-build-debug/Optimization
307
307

Process finished with exit code 0
```

So far so good but when I do (what I think is) the same at the command line:

```
jack@jack-MacBookPro:~/CLionProjects/Optimization$ g++ main.cpp -o main -O2 -larmadillo
jack@jack-MacBookPro:~/CLionProjects/Optimization$ ./main
```

I get the following output:

```
307

warning: SpMat::load(): inconsistent data in intMatSparse.mat
0

error: matrix multiplication: incompatible matrix dimensions: 0x0 and 307x3
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::logic_error'
  what():  matrix multiplication: incompatible matrix dimensions: 0x0 and 307x3
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Is it possible I need to link to the Armadillo library differently in order to access the sparse matrix functionality?

Thanks in advance.

Jack

Comment: What are the linker settings in CLion?

Comment: It uses a CMakeLists.txt file to link to libraries, these are the lines relevant to armadillo:

find_package(Armadillo REQUIRED)
include_directories(${ARMADILLO_INCLUDE_DIRS})
target_link_libraries(SETC ${ARMADILLO_LIBRARIES})